# PDO Prepared Statement Search w/ MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to create a search function, using PDO and MySQL, however I have run into trouble with how to include wildcards.
I have tested the following solutions:

```
$searchStr = $_POST['searchstr'];

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE %:search% ORDER BY `submitted` DESC");
$sth->bindParam(":search", $searchStr);
$sth->execute();
$r = $sth->fetchAll();
```

This results in a PDO error, because the wildcard symbols are outside the quotes (%'searchterm'%)
I then tried adding the wildcard symbols into the string passed to the parameter, however while it throws no errors, it does not return the correct results.

```
$searchStr = "%" . $_POST['searchstr'] . "%";

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE :search ORDER BY `submitted` DESC");
$sth->bindParam(":search", $searchStr);
$sth->execute();
$r = $sth->fetchAll();
```

How can I securely process the search with a prepared query, and used wildcards?
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you bindParam the fields you select? as in `bingParam('s','$firstname);`

Comment: @odetta this is PDO not mysqli

Comment: I did bind the parameters.